# Update all MYSQL table rows where value is greater than X ignore other

Tags: mysql

I have table in MYSQL lets say `THETABLE` with values `id`, `x`, `xx`...

**how to do this**: `UPDATE THETABLE WHERE x > 500 SET xx=xx+100`

I want to select all rows where `x` value greater than 500 and update `xx` by increasing them.

**optional:** After its done `x` should become `0` while `xx` now `600`.

Comment: `UPDATE 'THETABLE'  SET xx = xx+100  WHERE x>500;` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query syntax is wrong ... it should be below (`SET` comes before `WHERE`)

```
UPDATE THETABLE
SET xx = xx+100,
    x = 0
WHERE x > 500
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Update syntax is:

```
UPDATE <Table>
SET <>
WHERE <>
```

So:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET t.xx = t.xx + 100,
    t.x = 0
WHERE t.x > 500
```